# White screen problem in iphone 3gs

Tags: battery, iphone

Hello i have iPhone 3 gs and i have amazing problem when i lock my phone then after 15-20 seconds its shows white screen then i have to restart it what to do in this case is this a battery problem ? but if so then it does not switched off when i have connected to charger

I already have tried to reset it but not working..............

So, is white iphone 3gs all white or only the back of the phone is white?

Answer (score 1):

The iPhone 3 and iPhone 3GS era hardware show an all white screen most often when the hardware is damaged and needs a repair. When the devices were new, liquid corrosion and damage were the likely cause, but as these age it also could be a routine failure and not have anything to do with water.

- back it up (a successful backup means you might seek a screen replacement estimate)
- attempt to restore from iTunes
- recycle or repair or replace

Comment: Hi i just can not figure out my issues what should i do?

Comment: If an Apple store is close, go there. If not, you'll want to determine if you need to worry about backing up your contacts, songs, etc... or get help from someone that can guide you through that process. Open iTunes and search for "back up iPhone" in the help to get started..